# Trying to understand process state differences

Tags: process, operating-system, state

I was wondering what the difference between Microsoft's process states vs. other OS process states was?  I've researched see that there is a basic model for process states comprised of 5 states: New (added to ready queue), Ready (list of processes ready to execute), Running (currently running process), Waiting or Blocked (process put on hold to wait for I/o event or waiting for resource), and Terminated (all done).

All operating systems seem to have these 5 states.  Is there really a difference between Microsoft and others?

Comment: The question is very generic. What are the other Operating Systems you are referring to ?

Comment: I believe i figured it out.  I was going against Unix etc.  MS has 6 process states and Unix has 9.  Unix has two running processes (kernel and user) and MS has one.